# How to make +12v standby power from ATX power supply?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, atx

Can I make a 12v SB line from the existing lines on this ATX power supply? I'm told that +/- 10% voltage is acceptable. Can I combine a (red + orange + purple) **5V + 3.3V + 5VSB = 13.3VSB?**

I'm working on a Dell C8220 board with proprietary **18-pin, 8x +12V & 1x +12VSB & 9x Ground**.

[image]

Comment: removed the unrelated tags. Neither step-up power supplies nor color coding are subject of the question, even if the cables have all the nice colors :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't; that's not how power supplies work.

The "negative" part in all your voltage rails is the same voltage, actually even connected, so you can't connect them in series.

For that to work, these individual voltage supplies would need to be *isolated* from each other. The opposite is desirable within a PC: you want all voltages to be relative to the same chassis ground voltage.

Comment: I don't know how the negative part factors into my question.

Comment: you wanted to connect your voltage rails in series, so that voltages add up. That wouldn't work, unless the negative conductors were all isolated from each other.

Comment: Can I add components to make a 12vSB? Could you recommend action here? The board takes a 220v "switching" power supply. I'm curious about using my 120v psu as it puts out more than enough for the 200W to the server board. Thank you.

Comment: no, you realistically can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a few watts, you can absolutely add a 5v to 12v DC-DC converter. Just use a crimp splice to splice the 5VSB and another one for a ground wire and connect that to your 5 to 12 V converter and you're good to go. The 5Vsb is usually only rated for an amp or two, so only do this if you're going to be pulling just a small amount for something.

Comment: Although what you wrote is a valid information, please observe that is *not* what the Original Poster asked.